# Use Dynamic Text or "Place Holder" in Contact Form 7 Field

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, dynamic-text

I'm using Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension.
How do I get dynamic text to show when needed but a place holder to show if there is no dynamic text to populate the field?

Currently, I'm having two fields showing up one with the dynamic text and one blank, or just two blank fields.

Comment: This question seems to answer your issue https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309739/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-placeholder-on-get-field

Comment: This just saved me, Thank You!